# vertically central aligning an image inside a div?

Tags: html, css

I have a div which contain 2 images inside it.

First image's height is just as per div height but second image height is less then div height. I want to vertically central align this image which I have failed to do. Here is my markup, please advise me how to do this so that it will work in all current browsers.

Thanks

```
 <div class="left">
        <img alt="" src="Images/Logo.png" style=" border:2px dashed red;" />
        <img class=TI alt="Tayyiba Institute" src="Images/TayyibaInstitute.png" style=" border:2px dashed orange;" />
    </div>

    div.Container div.Left
{
width:50%;
float:left ;
display:inline;
}

div.Container div.Left img.TI
{        
 width:92px;
 height:95px;
 float:left;
 line-height:200px;
 vertical-align:middle;
 margin:auto 0 auto 0;
 display:block ;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well here's a lot of mistakes...let me go through 1 by 1...

1) No quotes here `class=TI`

2) Where's the container div over here? `div.Container div.Left img.TI`

You need to float your first image to the left and give `position: relative;` to the second image like this :

[My fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jGXtB/2/)

HTML

```
<div class="left">
    <img alt="" src="Images/Logo.png" style=" border:2px dashed red; float: left;" />
    <img class="TI" alt="Tayyiba Institute" src="http://www.cbfaizabad.org.in/images/bullet/0043_bullet2.png" style=" border:2px dashed orange;" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.Left
{
float:left ;
}

.TI
{        
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
}​
```

**SUGGESTION:** Clean up the CSS And learn more

Comment: Mr.Alien, thanks for your suggestion but your code is not a solution of problem. I don't want to display both image next to each other issues is as I explained second image is less in height and I want to vertically central align it. I just have tested it in firefox.

Comment: @haansi Did you saw I vertically aligned it?

Comment: Mr. Alien thanks for this. I just tested it in firefox and it was not. any suggestion please

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jGXtB/2/ doesn't work for you? I updated my answers fiddle too using a bigger image

Comment: If I am not wrong in my understanding you are fixing top margin ( 5px or 43px). While I want to vertically central align it

Comment: yup you need to do it like this

Answer (score 1):

Please, keep it simple.

Markup:

```
<div class="left"> 
    <img alt="" src="Images/Logo.png" /> 
    <img alt="" src="Images/TayyibaInstitute.png" /> 
</div>
```

Style sheet:

```
.left img { 
    vertical-align: middle; 
}
```

[With this result](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/nx3DN/).

Comment: Thanks NGLN, it worked but strange things is this if there are two images then it works fine (middle align vertically) but not if there is one image. Please guide how to do it with one image ? why it is ?

Comment: @haansi To what should that one image center then? Please consider searching to find your answer. Centering vertically is the most frequently asked CSS question here on Stack Overflow.